A covariant derivative computation in General Relativity
I am trying to compute $\nabla^\mu\nabla^\nu R_{\mu\nu}$.
I proceed as follows:
\begin{align}
\nabla^\mu\nabla^\nu R_{\mu\nu}&=g^{\mu\rho}g^{\nu\lambda}\nabla_\rho\nabla_\lambda R_{\mu\nu} \\
&=g^{\mu\rho}g^{\nu\lambda}\nabla_\rho(\partial_\lambda R_{\mu\nu}-\Gamma^\kappa{}_{\mu\lambda}R_{\kappa\nu}-\Gamma^\kappa{}_{\nu\lambda}R_{\mu\kappa})
\end{align}
How to compute $\nabla_\rho(\Gamma^\kappa_{\mu\lambda}R_{\kappa\nu})$ appearing in the above expression?

It certainly helps. Thanks!

The calculation aside, have u tried using the identity $\nabla^aG_{ab}=0$?

@KP99, this identity is very useful for the purpose of this calculation. Thanks for bringing it to my attention!
